# Customize Laravel Fortify Registration Error

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I am currently building my first laravel application for a school project.
I am using Laravel Jetstream, which might now was the best choice but its too late to change that now.

In the CreateNewUser.php File after the Validation the "create"-function does the following:

```
return User::create([...]);
```

I changed it to

```
if(condition) {
   $user = new User([...]);
   $user->save();
   return $user;
} else {
   return view('error);
}
```

I am now facing the problem that in case of the condition not applying, laravel gives me the following error:

[image: Laravel Error]

This does make sense to me, but after a few hours of looking through the code and browsing the interet, I havent been able to figure out how I can customize the code so I can return an error page.

I would be very happy if anyone of you could help me as I am now quite sure how to go on at this point.

Edit: After reviewing the question a second time, I noticed its maybe not clear why I am doing it that way. My Problem is, that I need to sync the user over a pivot table with a school after creating it. Maybe there is also a way to do that while creating the user? If there is, please let me know.

Comment: What's in your condition?
```if(condition)```

Comment: I am making an api call and if the response gives me an "okay" the condition is true. After that I am creating a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could likely sync your user of the to the pivot table in `RegisteredUserController.php` after the `$user` returned before the redirect to login:

```
public function store(Request $request,
                          CreatesNewUsers $creator): RegisterResponse
    {
        event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));

        //use the newly created $user here

        $this->guard->login($user);

        return app(RegisterResponse::class);
    }
```

Comment: Thats also what I thought about, but what do I return when the condition is false? When I try to return an empty user it just fails, in my case because of the email validation

Comment: Are you doing email validation beyond the ```Validator:make...``` in the ```create()``` method in ```CreateNewUser.php```? If validation fails here the errors will be returned to the Register blade view and you will not even make it to ```RegisteredUserController.php```. In the code above you should only be dealing with a successful ```$user``` object.

Comment: Okay, maybe this is just generally a wrong approach from my side. The problem is that I need to make different api calls which then tell me wheter or not creating the user (I am creating the same user on another app) was successfull. Do you think I can return an artificial wrong validation?

Comment: I think in your case you could make use of the "After Validation Hook". You could make the API call and validate within the method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook

Comment: I just found a solution. I am just throwing a custom validation error when the API-Call fails. This seems to be the easiest solution. But still thanks a lot!